# Alarm Manager not setting alarms for particular dates or over 24 hours

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Here is my function for trigger an alarm it is working fine for setting alarms at particular time in the day.But when i tried to set alarm for next day or over 24 hours it will work and doesn't notify me.I have checked some solutions but couldn't find an answer.

**Alarm Manger Code.java**

```
 public void triggerAlarmManager(int alarmTriggerTime,int position) {
   // activealarm();

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

 alarmIntent.putExtra("test",news_data.getName());
                             pendingIntent = 
  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,position+1, alarmIntent, 
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // get a Calendar object with current time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // add alarmTriggerTime seconds to the calendar object
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTriggerTime);


    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //get instance of alarm manager
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);//set alarm manager with entered timer by converting into milliseconds

    int days = alarmTriggerTime / 1440;
    int hours = (alarmTriggerTime % 1440)/60;
    int mins = alarmTriggerTime % 60;

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set for " + "Days:"+days+" Hours:"+hours+" Minutes:"+mins, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent1=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("ret","ret");
    context.startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your updated code:**

```
public void triggerAlarmManager(int alarmTriggerTime,int position) {
   // activealarm();

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

 alarmIntent.putExtra("test",news_data.getName());
                             pendingIntent = 
  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,position+1, alarmIntent, 
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar setCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    // get a Calendar object with current time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // add alarmTriggerTime seconds to the calendar object
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTriggerTime);

    if(cal.before(setCalendar))
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //get instance of alarm manager
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);//set alarm manager with entered timer by converting into milliseconds

    int days = alarmTriggerTime / 1440;
    int hours = (alarmTriggerTime % 1440)/60;
    int mins = alarmTriggerTime % 60;

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set for " + "Days:"+days+" Hours:"+hours+" Minutes:"+mins, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent1=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("ret","ret");
    context.startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and how it solves the issue. For us all to learn.

Comment: If you want to repeat the alarm every day then you have to add this line in your code that i put in your code
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
This will repeat the alarm  after one day on same time.

Comment: My problem in the code is that it is setting alarm within a day at any time but when i set alarm for next day or any particular date and day it will not ring.I don't need repeating alarms.

Answer (score 0):

To set an alarm for any other day, do this:

```
cal.set(Calendar.DATE,11);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8)
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0)
```

This sets an alarm for 11th of the month at 8am